# Constants , values and decorators in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand the topics "constants" , "values" and "decorators" in angular js what I got from the document is they are some special services and the differences among them .
 But if someone could elaborate me what are they used for with some examples . I already googled but didn't find any useful article yet.

Comment: I don't know if you can understand french, but a guy named Grafikart made very good tutorials about that. you can find the difference bewteen services, factories and such here : https://www.grafikart.fr/formations/angularjs/services

Answer (score 0):

**Constant**

> A constant can be injected everywhere. A constant can not be
>   intercepted by a decorator, that means that the value of a constant
>   should never be changed (though it is still possible to change it
>   programmatically in Angular 1.x).

```
angular.module('app', []);

app.constant('MOVIE_TITLE', 'The Matrix');

.controller('MyController', function (MOVIE_TITLE) {
  expect(MOVIE_TITLE).toEqual('The Matrix');
});
```

**Value**

> A value is nothing more than a simple injectable value. The value can
>   be a string, number but also a function. Value differs from constant
>   in that value can not be injected into configurations, but it can be
>   intercepted by decorators.

```
angular.module('app', []);

.value('movieTitle', 'The Matrix');

.controller('MyController', function (movieTitle) {
  expect(movieTitle).toEqual('The Matrix');
})
```

**Decorator**

> A decorator can modify or encapsulate other providers. There is one
>   exception and that a constant cannot be decorated.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.value('movieTitle', 'The Matrix');

app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('movieTitle', function ($delegate) {
    return $delegate + ' - starring Keanu Reeves';
  });
});

app.controller('MyController', function (movieTitle) {
  expect(movieTitle).toEqual('The Matrix - starring Keanu Reeves');
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Ghazanfar for the reply it cleared my doubt my could you also let me know what are their practical use ?